# Can you name faces/regions in Meshlab?

Tags: meshlab

I have some STL's to model in OpenFOAM but the boundaries are not named.  Can I select a group of triangles and name them in Meshlab?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a quality to a set of faces, so this could be used as a way to "put a label which is a number, not a name" to each zone. But I doubt that openFoam will understand these quality values as names.